# Transaction rejected by our node. Blockchain receive API

Tags: api, blockchain.info, transaction-malleability

I use the Blockchain.info receive API with great succes.
Yesterday I created a new address: 1MMVp6fzZ6QrVYXg9iRSJb5PsM8crq5iMZ
It received 1.5 BTC and was transferred to my BTC address (unfonfirmed). With transaction hash: 79ff50d749d1d8099e68ac04dba4e64645322e49e671326d74d871bfd0f868eb

Today I logged in on my wallet, the unconfirmed transaction was gone.
Now if I search that hash on blockchain.info, I get following message: Transaction rejected by our node. Reason: Transaction was previously accepted but has been pruned from our database.

Will the Blockchain API retry to send the BTC to my address or are they forever lost on the generated address? Would it make sense to make a small payment to that address so the Blockchain API would resend the whole amount?

Why does this happen?

Comment: How much transaction fees did you add to that transaction?

Comment: Oh, blockchain.info generated that address, and they were supposed to forward that amount to another btc address and it didn't happen?  And this is a free service and no customer support?  Well, sucks to be you ... :-(

Comment: It seems to be a mixup at blockchain.info. They show the deposit as confirmed in some places and not in others.